# I am facing FileNotFound Exception.. Please help me out for this

Tags: .net

Could not load referenced assembly "D:\Dev\Prime\Proj\PRIME.Framework.root\PRIME.AppInterfaces\bin\Debug\PRIME.AppInterfaces.dll".  Caught a FileNotFoundException saying "Could not load file or assembly 'D:\Dev\Prime\Proj\PRIME.Framework.root\PRIME.AppInterfaces\bin\Debug\PRIME.AppInterfaces.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.".  D:\Dev\Prime\Proj\PRIME.BusinessLogicLayer\ResGen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you go to the path `D:\Dev\Prime\Proj\PRIME.Framework.root\PRIME.AppInterfaces\bin\Debug` and check for existence of the dll?
If it is present, do check the framework version in both of them. If one of them is different try to bring it to same version.

Answer (score 0):

Use the fusion log viewer to debug assembly loading issues.  It comes with .net sdk, run it, set it log errors, and then run your app and refresh.  It should list the error.  Open the error and see which dll it can find.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx